Issues with i915 USB-C Connection using it for display purposes in Ubuntu 22.04
I'm experiencing a problem with my Ubuntu 22.04 setup on my laptop that has both Intel iGPU and NVIDIA GPU (GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile). 2 different Dell screens refuse to recognise any output with any of the 4 USB-C cables I tried that used to work until today.
I Initially though it was a problem with my Nvidia card/driver and posted a topic on the Nvidia boards: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/usb-c-monitor-not-detected-with-nvidia-driver-535-on-ubuntu-22-04/290886/3
Turns out it probably is the i915 driver using my USB-C that's the root of the problem.
I face persistent errors from the i915 driver when using my USB-C port for display output. Attempting to resolve this, I switched from MS Hybrid to Discrete mode in the BIOS, hoping to rely solely on the NVIDIA GPU.
Despite this switch, the USB-C connection issues persist, and a new problem with screen brightness being too dim has arisen — I've lost the ability to adjust it.
Initial USB-C Error Messages:
[ 42.639037] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* AUX USBC1/DDI TC1/PHY TC1: did not complete or timeout within 10ms (status 0xad40023f)

Things I tried:

Switching to Noveau driver
Upgrading the kernel using the LiquorixPPA.
Reinstalling and reconfiguring both Intel and NVIDIA graphics drivers.
Updating all software short of  switching to 24.04 Beta
Checking and replacing the USB-C cable.
Switching from MSHybrid to Discrete mode, this cause my screen to be very dim and no brightness controls worked so I switched back because it did not solve the main issue.

I haven't been able to try the HDMI port lacking a cable right now.
Upgrading the bios seems a daunting dangerous task, especially since this is not a laptop of on of the big brands and I have no idea how or what about the BIOS.
And in the process of all these changes I lost my ability to switch to "Performance" mode, I only have "Balanced" and "Power Save" left
Debug info for my graphics card is in the Nvidia topic btw
Edit:
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 02)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bd (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (16) I219-V (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
2c:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)

prime-select nvidia
Info: selecting the nvidia profile
Deleting /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
Updating the initramfs. Please wait for the operation to complete:
|W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amd/amd_sev_fam19h_model1xh.sbin for module ccp
Done

lspci -vnn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:4626] (rev 0c) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:2520] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])


HDMI seems to also not work, so that is either a different problem, or the same problem.

Somehow this problem went away after a few more restarts without any other specific actions taken.
So it’s solved, but not satisfyingly.
